# how to run a mixed fortran/c project

Tags: c, fortran

i'm trying to run a project that mixes FORTRAN and C, the main program is in C (not my own code).

i tried eclipse for parallel application but it didn't recognize the call of FORTRAN subroutines from C.

Then i tried configuring visual studio for mixed programmation [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/configuring-visual-studio-for-mixed-language-applications), but i didn't know what to do next, do i need to make two sepatrated projects one for c the other for fortran under a fortran IDE?

anyone have an idea if i need some configuration for eclipse or have an idea about using Visual Studio for Mixed-Language Applications ?

Comment: Did you write the code? Did the code work for anyone else?

Comment: no i have mentioned that the code is not mine, but i have also the executable of the application and it works perfectly

Comment: Which compilers are you using, especially for the FORTRAN sources?

Comment: gcc for c and gfortran for FORTRAN

Comment: `gcc` and `gfortran` do not got together with Visual Studio. To use the latter you could use Visual Studio Express for the C part. And look around at the Intel site for their most recommended FORTRAN compiler, for which they use to offer VS support also: http://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compilers